# Display query custom table on Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to display query from custom table on my wordpress page:

```
table name: wp_formmaker_submits
```

field to display: element_value (with 6 rows on each data)

This is the query result:

> 2014-07-2211:13:00SpeedMacLindseyNewYork2014-07-2211:22:00FedExJackChloeLondon2014-07-2211:42:00DHLSteveDannoHawaii

It should appear like

```
> 2014-07-22 | 11:13:00 | Speed | Mac | Lindsey | New York
> 2014-07-22 | 11:22:00 | FedEx | Jack | Chloe | London
> 2014-07-22 | 11:42:00 | DHL | Steve | Danno | Hawaii
```

I need help with the `<tr>` and `<td>` structure, so the html table will look properly.

This is my code:

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT element_value FROM wp_formmaker_submits WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()");
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><td>Date</td><td>Time</td><td>Carrier</td><td>Driver</td><td>Co Driver</td><td>Destination</td></tr>";
foreach($result as $wp_formmaker_submits){
echo "<td>".$wp_formmaker_submits->element_value."</td>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

printr:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 7 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 1 [element_value] => 2014-07-22 [group_id] => 2 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:14:01 [ip] => ::1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 8 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 2 [element_value] => 11:13:00 [group_id] => 2 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:14:01 [ip] => ::1 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 9 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 3 [element_value] => Speed [group_id] => 2 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:14:01 [ip] => ::1 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 10 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 4 [element_value] => Mac [group_id] => 2 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:14:01 [ip] => ::1 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 11 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 5 [element_value] => Lindsey [group_id] => 2 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:14:01 [ip] => ::1 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 12 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 6 [element_value] => New York [group_id] => 2 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:14:01 [ip] => ::1 ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 13 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 1 [element_value] => 2014-07-22 [group_id] => 3 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:22:50 [ip] => ::1 ) [7] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 14 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 2 [element_value] => 11:22:00 [group_id] => 3 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:22:50 [ip] => ::1 ) [8] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 15 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 3 [element_value] => FedEx [group_id] => 3 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:22:50 [ip] => ::1 ) [9] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 16 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 4 [element_value] => Jack [group_id] => 3 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:22:50 [ip] => ::1 ) [10] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 17 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 5 [element_value] => Chloe [group_id] => 3 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:22:50 [ip] => ::1 ) [11] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 18 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 6 [element_value] => Hawaii [group_id] => 3 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:22:50 [ip] => ::1 ) [12] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 19 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 1 [element_value] => 2014-07-22 [group_id] => 4 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:43:31 [ip] => ::1 ) [13] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 20 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 2 [element_value] => 11:42:00 [group_id] => 4 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:43:31 [ip] => ::1 ) [14] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 21 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 3 [element_value] => DHL [group_id] => 4 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:43:31 [ip] => ::1 ) [15] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 22 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 4 [element_value] => Steve [group_id] => 4 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:43:31 [ip] => ::1 ) [16] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 23 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 5 [element_value] => Danno [group_id] => 4 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:43:31 [ip] => ::1 ) [17] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 24 [form_id] => 10 [element_label] => 6 [element_value] => Hawaii [group_id] => 4 [date] => 2014-07-22 04:43:31 [ip] => ::1 ) )
```

Comment: What is your current table structure? Since it is a custom table, do you have control over altering the structure of the table and saving data in different columns? e.g. time, date, carrier etc in separate columns instead of storing all the things in a single column OR adding suffix/prefix with some special characters for each different data when storing. Your job would become easier if you are able to do so. But if you are getting all the data as combined without any separator, I think it's not easily achievable even with string manipulation except first three fields.

Comment: the table source is from wp plugin, WP Form Maker. the full field on the table are: id, form_id, element_label, element_value, date, ip

Comment: The WP Form maker plugin should have been storing the values at least with key/value pair in database.                                         Do one thing, do print_r($result) before the for loop and see what it displays. Also, see if there is any in built method provided by plugin to fetch such data instead of making custom SQL query.

Comment: thanks WisdmLabs, I'm totally noob on coding. Is there any reference link? I put the print_r result on my question above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just edited your code. See if this works -

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT element_value FROM wp_formmaker_submits WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()");
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Date</th><th>Time</th><th>Carrier</th><th>Driver</th><th>Co Driver</th><th>Destination</th></tr>";

$count = 0;

foreach($result as $wp_formmaker_submits){

    $new = $wp_formmaker_submits->element_label;

    if($new == 1){

        if( $count > 0 )
            echo "</tr>";

        echo "<tr>";
    }

    echo "<td>".$wp_formmaker_submits->element_value."</td>";

    $count++;
}
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: still not working, the 2nd data is still on the right side, <tr> not working